# getTitle EditText and Database cursor

Tags: android, cursor, android-edittext

I am using an `EditText` as a search field and trying to get the users input from there read into my Cursor. My code crashes because editText shows as an `int` and not a `long`.

If I manually input a number it works and system does not crash. What am I doing wrong in converting `int` into `long`?

This is my code:

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
db.open();
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1); 
String s = edit.getText().toString();
long n = Integer.parseInt(s); 
Cursor c = db.getTitle(n);
if (c.moveToFirst())
    DisplayTitle(c);
```

This code works but I have to input manually the position for `getTitle`:

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
db.open();
Cursor c = db.getTitle(6);
if (c.moveToFirst())
    DisplayTitle(c);
```

Please help.